# Pandas sum elements pairwise based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataset:

```
A    B     c     condition
1    5     7     1
7    8     0     1
9    0     3     1
2    5     4     2
6    6     3     2
9    9     0     2
```

I would like to sum each respective element in each condition with each other. So, in condition 1 the element on the first row in the first column should be summed with the first element of row 1, column 1 in condition 2 (being, 1+2 =3). So the result should look like this:

```
A    B     c     
3    10    11    
13   14    3     
18   9     3
```

I searched and found some solutions by doing this with iloc but this is very ineffective since I have 20 conditions and each condition contains 57 rows. I guess you could use a loop to go through the conditions, but that doesn't solve the fact that you still need to define the position of each element with iloc.

Comment: Is the amount of conditions same for each condition?

Comment: Yes 57 rows in each condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a sequence by condition groups to indicate the row, then groupby sequence and sum.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 7, 9, 2, 6, 9],
                   'B': [5, 8, 0, 5, 6, 9],
                   'C': [7, 0, 3, 4, 3, 0],
                   'condition': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]})

df['seq'] = df.groupby('condition').cumcount()
df.groupby('seq')[['A', 'B', 'C']].sum().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```py
    A   B   C
0   3  10  11
1  13  14   3
2  18   9   3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can **split the dataframe into a list of dataframes by your condition**, then **sum list of dataframe** together, with your example it would look like this:

```
data = {"A": [1, 7, 9, 2, 6, 9], "B": [5, 8, 0, 5, 6, 9], "c": [7, 0, 3, 4, 3, 0], "condition": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]}
df_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
lst_cond = [1, 2]
lst_df_splited_by_cond = [df_data[df_data["condition"] == cond].reset_index().drop(["condition", "index"], axis=1) for cond in lst_cond]
```

first element of lst_df_splited_by_cond would look like:

```
    A   B   c
0   1   5   7
1   7   8   0
2   9   0   3
```

second element of lst_df_splited_by_cond would look like:

```
    A   B   c
0   2   5   4
1   6   6   3
2   9   9   0
```

Then **use reduce from functools**

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda x, y: x.add(y, fill_value=0), lst_df_splited_by_cond)
```

which returns a dataframe of sum:

```
    A   B   c
0   3   10  11
1   13  14  3
2   18  9   3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner for you:

```
df.groupby('condition').apply(lambda x: x.values).values.sum()
```